# Elasticsearch NEST: specifying Id explicitly seems to cause inconsistent search scores

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a model class that looks like this:

```
public class MySearchDocument
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int DBID { get; set; }
}
```

We always use bulk indexing. By default our searches do a relatively simple `multi_match` with more weight given to `ID` and `Name`, like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "burger",
            "fields": [
                "ID^1.2",
                "Name^1.1",
                "Description"
            ],
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true
        }
    }
}
```

I was previously just relying on [Id inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html), allowing Elasticsearch to use my `ID` property for its Id purposes, but for a few reasons it has become preferable to use `DBID` as the Id property in Elasticsearch. I tried this 3 different ways, **separately and in combo**:

1. Explicitly when bulk indexing: `new BulkIndexOperation<MySearchDocument>(d) { Id = d.DBID }`
2. In the `ConnectionSettings` using `DefaultMappingFor<MySearchDocument>(d => d.IdProperty(p => p.DBID))`
3. Using an attribute on `MySearchDocument`: `[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = nameof(DBID))]`

Any and all of these seem to work as expected; the `_id` field in the indexed documents are being set to my `DBID` property. However, in my integration tests, search results are anything but expected. Specifically, I have a test that:

1. Creates a new index from scratch.
2. Populates it with a handful of `MySearchDocument`s
3. Issues a `Refresh` on the index just to make sure it's ready.
4. Issues a search.
5. Asserts that the results come back in the expected order.

With Id inference, this test consistently passes. When switching the Id field using any or all of the techniques above, it passes *maybe* half the time. Looking at the raw results, the correct documents are always returned, but the `_score` often varies for the same document from test run to test run. Sometimes the varying score is the one associated with the document whose `ID` field matches the search term, other times it's the score of a different document.

I've tried coding the test to run repeatedly and in parallel. I've tried waiting several seconds *after* issuing `Refresh`, just to be sure the index is ready. None of these make a difference - the test passes consistently with Id inference, and is consistently inconsistent without. I know nothing in this world is truly random, so I feel like I must be missing something here. Let me know if more details would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One detail to add, not sure if it's important: we are using [auto mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html) when creating the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search relevancy scores are calculated per shard, and a hashing algorithm on the value of `_id` determines into which primary shard a given document will be indexed.

It *sounds* like you may be seeing the effects of this when indexing a **small sample** of documents across `N > 1` primary shards; in this case, the local relevancy scores may be different enough to manifest in some odd looking `_score`s returned. With a larger set of documents and even distribution, differences in local shard scores diminish.

There are a couple of approaches that you can take to overcome this for testing purposes:

1. Use a single primary shard

or

2. Use [`dfs_query_then_fetch`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#dfs-query-then-fetch) when making the search request. This tells Elasticsearch to take the local relevancy scores first in order to calculate global relevancy scores, then use global scores for `_score`. [There is a slight overhead to using `dfs_query_then_fetch`](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch).

Take a look also at the section ["Relevance is Broken!"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html) from the Elasticsearch Definitive guide; although the guide refers to Elasticsearch 2.x, much of it is still very much relevant for later versions.

Comment: You sir are a miracle worker. Going down to 1 shard worked like a charm. Thanks!